# PHP is throwing an error while executing add function

Tags: php

PHP is throwing an error at this line of code:

```
$filingOpposition->add(new \DateInterval('P4M'));
```

This is the error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function add() on boolean in C:\ss.php

Why is PHP throwing this error?

Edit: I was able to fix it and it worked. Thanks everyone for spending time

Answer (score 2):

The error message means that `$fillingOpposition` is a boolean (true or false) on which the method `->add()` does not exist. You should carefully check the code where you initialise `$fillingOpposition`, and make sure that it's of the type you want it to be.

If you edit your question to include that initialisation, we could have a look.